# Get the index of item in a list given its property

Tags: c#, linq

In `MyList` `List<Person>` there may be a `Person` with its `Name` property set to "ComTruise". I need the index of first occurrence of "ComTruise" in `MyList`, but not the entire `Person` element.

What I'm doing now is:

```
string myName = ComTruise;
int thatIndex = MyList.SkipWhile(p => p.Name != myName).Count();
```

If the list is very large, is there a more optimal way to get the index?

Comment: That's pretty much what IndexOf does...

Comment: Is MyList your own collection or is it List<Person>?

Comment: Sorry, corrected that. How would be the syntax of IndexOf?

Comment: Do you need just the first instance of it or all indexes? `IndexOf` will only return the index of the first one it comes across.

Comment: The first instance looks ok for me.

Comment: Well, since it's not actually a `List<T>`, you _could_ use `myList.Select((person, index) => new { Person = person, Index = index }).FirstOrDefault(entry => entry.Person.Name == myName);` but honestly, I'm not sure if that's necessary "better" than what you have (though it would give you a `null` result rather than `Count` if the item doesn't exist in the list. This might be more intuitive then the "doesn't exist" magic value for `thatIndex` being equal to `MyList.Count`)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As it's an `ObservableCollection`, you can try this

```
int index = MyList.IndexOf(MyList.Where(p => p.Name == "ComTruise").FirstOrDefault());
```

It will return `-1` if "ComTruise" doesn't exist in your collection.

As mentioned in the comments, this performs two searches. You can optimize it with a for loop.

```
int index = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < MyList.Count; i++)
{
    //case insensitive search
    if(String.Equals(MyList[i].Name, "ComTruise", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) 
    {
        index = i;
        break;
    } 
}
```

Comment: So, you first find it and then look for it again? That's quite inefficient.

Comment: You're right, if the list is quite large, a For loop would be better. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Why did you change the comparison to match on substrings? For example, the name of `"X-ComTruise"` would match your “case insensitive search”.

Comment: Because it's one of those days ;)

Comment: Instead of using MyList.Where(..).FirstOrDefault()) you could use MyList.FirstOrDefault(...) to make the code even simpler :)

Answer (score 47):

You could use [FindIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx)

```
string myName = "ComTruise";
int myIndex = MyList.FindIndex(p => p.Name == myName);
```

Note: [FindIndex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca.aspx) returns -1 if no item matching the conditions defined by the supplied predicate can be found in the list.

Comment: Arg, actually it's an ObservableCollection and not a List, is there something equivalent? I thought it was the same in this particular case.

Comment: It works very well if I convert my ObservableCollection to a List with .ToList() method. Thank you!

Comment: Cracking, that will certainly sort you out, but you can do it without the conversion as well (some other answers have already shown how =D ).

Comment: Info: returns -1 if not found

Comment: Finding "ComTruise" is a Mission Impossible.

Answer (score 8):

It might make sense to write a simple extension method that does this:

```
public static int FindIndex<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> collection, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
            return i;
        i++;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var p = MyList.Where(p => p.Name == myName).FirstOrDefault();
int thatIndex = -1;
if (p != null)
{
  thatIndex = MyList.IndexOf(p);
}

if (p != -1) ...
```