# Selecting first or default index of list item where property in list matches a property in another list?

Tags: c#, linq

I have this code:

```
int index = Convert.ToInt32(PointSeries.XValues.FirstOrDefault(e => this.PointsRects.Any(ep => ep.BottomLeft.X == e)));
```

This returns me the item in the `PointSeries.XValues` list where the x value matches the bottom left in the `PointsRects` list. I want the index of the item in the `PointSeries.XValues` list (of type `List<double>`).

Comment: I'm confused on what values are in your lists and you didn't show us what `PointSeriesValues` is. If you are looking for "the index of an item" then you should be able to use [`List.IndexOf()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17(v=vs.110).aspx), e.g., `var theIndexInsidePointSeriesValues = PointSeriesValues.IndexOf(index)`, where `index` here is an Item in the collection and not an array/list index (that is to say, I think your variable name is confusing).

Comment: This question may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264281/get-the-index-of-item-in-a-list-given-its-property

Comment: Sorry, the PointSeries.XValues is a List<double>

Answer (score 1):

Since you have `List<T>`, you can mix LINQ with the concrete [`FindIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1xzf2ca(v=vs.110).aspx) method specifically provided for that purpose:

```
int index = PointSeries.XValues.FindIndex(
    e => this.PointsRects.Any(ep => ep.BottomLeft.X == e));
```

The returned value is

> The zero-based index of the first occurrence of an element that matches the conditions defined by match, if found; otherwise, –1.

In case `PointRects` list is big, you can further optimize it by building `HashSet<double>` and replacing `Any` with `HashSet.Contains`:

```
int index = PointSeries.XValues.FindIndex(
    new HashSet<double>(this.PointsRects.Select(ep => ep.BottomLeft.X)).Contains);
```